# jQuery on click doesnt work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile

Why click doesn't work on mobile? works on PC

There were couple of other questions but none of the answers work. I tried making the element clickable by adding **onclick = "void(0)"**, added **href**, added **touchend** and **touchstart**. Nothing helps.

```js
$('.size-list-item').on('click touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".size-list-item").removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-list size-list-items">
  <a class="size-list-item" data-type="25m2" href="#000" onclick="void(0)">25м2</a>
  <a class="size-list-item active" data-type="50m2" href="#000" onclick="void(0)">50м2</a>
  <a class="size-list-item" data-type="80m2" href="#000" onclick="void(0)">80м2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can refer this and use this to solve your problem **http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/**

Comment: SOA #1. It works perfectly on LG G2 with Android 6 and Chrome 55. Can you tell us exactly what and where doesn't work?

Comment: This got little more complex and I am super confused http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655144/jquery-on-click-does-not-work-with-let-variable-declaration-but-wo

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are removing a class and then adding a class to the same element. So it cancels it out. Also try adding "touchstart" instead of "touchend".

Also, since you have onclick="void()" in the elements it will stop every click on this element working, so it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Wrong. Class is removed from all `.size-list-item` elements. Then, it's added back on clicked element. Author uses `toggleClass` which checks if element has certain class and adds it when it has not. So nothing cancels out here. He could use `addClass` though, because there's no need for checking if the class is applied when we intentionally remove it before.

Comment: It's not wrong. toggleClass changes what the existing class is. At the point of: $(".size-list-item").removeClass('active'); the class is gone. Then doing -  $(this).toggleClass('active'); adds it again, because 'this' refers to  $(".size-list-item")

Comment: That's exactly what the author wants. In order to mark clicked element as `.active` you need to remove the class from **all** previously active elements and **then** add the class to one selected element. ;-)

Comment: Really? Where do they mention that? All I Can see is this question - jQuery on click doesnt work on mobile
Why click doesn't work on mobile? works on PC

There were couple of other questions but none of the answers work. I tried making the element clickable by adding onclick = "void(0)", added href, added touchend and touchstart. Nothing helps

Comment: As per your edit, `onclick="void(0)"` will **not** stop clicks from working. In fact, it's not gonna do anything. `void(0)` is simply `undefined`. It's silly and not needed, but it's not changing any behaviour.

Comment: *They* don't explicitly mention what is the expected behaviour. Although, looking and the code and things that author already tired to do, it's rather easy to conclude that he wants to set a class `.active` to `a` element that user clicks. Since *usually* it means that only 1 element should be visually active, it's clear that he wants to remove the class from other elements that are not clicked. There's no need to argue — in the future you could just test a code and *then* answer. #NoHardFeelings ;-)

Comment: Oh, wait. Author actually **do** mention that. What's funnier, quoting my first comment in different discussion! [Look here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655144/jquery-on-click-does-not-work-with-let-variable-declaration-but-wo#comment70509097_41655144)

Comment: @WiktorBednarz  no need to be rude. I can play that game too #NoHardFeelings ;)

Comment: you're right, sometimes I get grumpy when I'm hungry. I'm sorry if it came out to be rude. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with the click, it is working fine. In WKWebView you need you need to set the viewport if you want to control scaling or general sizing. Just put this in your html it will work fine :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```