# jQuery ".on( 'click' ,....)" does not work with LET variable declaration. But works VAR

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, mobile

Is this a jquery bug? I have a simple click event. When I use LET to declare some variables with image links, the click event stops working on my ipad (chrome). When I switch to LET all works.

PS: I had another question with the same code but this is completely different.

```js
// WHEN I USE "VAR" ".on( 'click' ,....)"
// works on mobile. With "LET" it does not.

let imageLink25 = "http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1701/58/89fe5a582b92.png ";
let imageLink50 = "http: //i056.radikal.ru/1701/3e/0c7dcfd4956b.png";
let imageLink80 = "http://s011.radikal.ru/i318/1701/56/48fc3db701a0.png";

$('.size-list-item').on('click touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".size-list-item").removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-list size-list-items">
  <a class="size-list-item" data-type="25m2" href="#000" onclick="void(0)">25м2</a>
  <a class="size-list-item active" data-type="50m2" href="#000" onclick="void(0)">50м2</a>
  <a class="size-list-item" data-type="80m2" href="#000" onclick="void(0)">80м2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove this line: `$(".size-list-item").removeClass('active');` and add a `;` to the end of your JS code sample.

Comment: Why? It will be harder understand that it is working....

Comment: You are removing a class and then toggling the same class on the same element. `$(".size-list-item")` and `$(this)` are the same elements. Removing the class and toggling means remove and add at the same time, which results in no change at all. Also, if you don't want your imageLinks to change (as in accidentally), you could make those `let`s `const`s.

Comment: Class is removed from all .size-list-item elements. Then, it's added back on clicked element. Author uses toggleClass which checks if element has certain class and adds it when it has not =)

Comment: Oh hold on, I didn't see the HTML example and understand what you are doing there. I don't understand the `let` part though. Your code sample doesn't show any usings of those `let`s

Comment: yes. I dont use those variables. But even as it is it doesnt work on mobile with LET. With VAR works fine....

Comment: I need sleep or something because I didn't see the obvious. See Frank Noel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The let variables is only available in it's block scope. In your case, you can't use the three let variables if they are outside the jQuery block.

Here's a link that explain well the difference between var, let and const.
https://www.sitepoint.com/preparing-ecmascript-6-let-const/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you even used the defined variables `imageLink*`.

It's possible that your browser doesn't support `let` statements. According to [Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=let) it's fully supported by default in Chrome 49 and above.

If it's not supported it'll cause syntax error preventing JavaScript from further execution. That means, your `click` event will never be set!

**Check which version of Chrome you're running on your iPad. If it's below 49, that's your answer.**

However, if the version is between 41 and 48 it's still possible to use `let`, but you need to be in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Simply, it requires you to put `'use strict';` at the beginning of your JavaScript code. ;-)